# OpenCL concurrent execution

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, nvidia

I seem to have read somewhere that all work-items within a work-group execute concurrently. I have also read that a Work-group are handled by streaming a multiprocessor. But what if the work-group size is chosen such that the number of work-items exceed the number of streaming processors in a streaming multiprocessor (nvidia)? Then they can not be executed concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to different levels, where *concurrently* has different interpretations:

- the OpenCL execution model, a specification describing how tasks are executed on the device. In this model, all work items in a ND-range kernel command execute *concurrently*, and work items within a work group can communicate using local memory, and can be synchronized.
- the hardware processing the tasks. In this case, *concurrently* is usually interpreted as "executing an instruction at the same time", but it could also be interpreted as "in flight in a core at the same time" (a larger set of work items).